# How do I add files to a folder until a certain size limit is reached?

Tags: shell-script, mv, size

I have a folder with 1.5 million files (mail files) of various sizes.  I want to create a directory, for example `a`, and move (`mv`) some of these files (which all start with a numeric timestamp) into folder `a`, until folder `a` is of up to a specified size.  How would I do this?

Avoiding any procedural `for` or `while` loops would be a plus (i.e. one line) but anything that works is great!

Comment: post one of your exemplary filenames *with a numeric timestamp*

Comment: I doubt that a simple approach is possible. There is implicit cumulated size measuring with (a) the size of a volume / filesystem, (b) with quota, and (c) with ulimits. But none of those works with `mv` i.e. existing files only with newly created (or changed) ones.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, use [datapacker](https://github.com/jgoerzen/datapacker/wiki)

Answer (score 1):

```
max_k=1000
sum=0
target_dir_path="/target/dir"
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%k %p\0' |
   while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' line; do
       size="${line%% *}"
       path="${line#* }"
       sum=$((sum+size))
       if [ "$sum" -le "$max_k" ]; then
           printf "%s\0" "$path"
       else
           break
       fi
    done | xargs -0 echo mv -t "target_dir_path"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create special LV (or partition) of desired size and mount it under your 'a' directory.

If you want to leave some spare space, combine it with quota.

There was similar question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148715/how-to-set-limit-on-directory-size-in-linux